# How do I convert row into CLOB in the applied trigger after update?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

The idea is, I want to clone the record as a **CLOB** when it is updated.
Why do it in such a way?
There are two different applications **A1** and **A2**, **A1** is depended on by **A2**.
Based on **A1** values, calculations are made for values for **A2**.

The **A2** process runs just once per day to calculate the values, but for A1 every field in the **TABLE_NAME** in question can be altered several times a day and doesn't have a history.

The aim is to create a history which is a CLOB field in a table "**NEW_TABLE**" of automatic form.

*Sorry for my English, but if something is not understandable I can rewrite the question*

My Code Here:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME
AFTER  UPDATE
   ON TABLE_NAME 
   FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE
    row_record                  NEW_TABLE%rowtype;
    c_xml                       CLOB;   


    FUNCTION GetXML(a_tablela varchar2, a_key_1 varchar2, a_key_2 varchar2)
      RETURN CLOB
      is
       x_xml CLOB;
    BEGIN      
      select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from '||a_tablela||' where key_1 = '''||a_key_1||''' and key_2 = '''||a_key_2||'''') into x_xml from dual;              
      return x_xml;
    END;
BEGIN

    --** TABLE_NAME Automatically fetches all columns and transforms them to CLOB
    c_xml := GetXML('TABLE_NAME', :new.key_1, :new.key_2);
    if c_xml is not null then 
        row_record.TABLE_NAME :=c_xml; 
    end if;                


    INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE VALUES row_record;


EXCEPTION
   when others then
        raise_application_error(-20000,'ERROR: '||to_char(sqlcode));

END;
```

Now I get error:

> **ORA-04091**: table **TABLE_NAME** is mutating, trigger/function may not see it.

when I get this record across **SELECT** statement.

How do I convert row into CLOB in the applied **TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE** ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't select from the table the trigger is on, but it isn't clear why you need to; are you setting another column in the same row? Please show the trigger you have and explain what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't use a select statement is because you're in the trigger, and the table is changing, or 'mutating', as the error says. The only way you can get the data from the row that's being updated here is using new and old:

`old.column1` 
`new.column1`

Old being the value of the column before the update, new being the value after the update. 

Example:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME
AFTER  UPDATE
    ON TABLE_NAME 
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    l_string := 'This is the old value for column 1: ' || old.column1 || '. This is the new value: ' || new.column1;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_string);
END;
```

You won't be able to use dbms_xmlgen because it uses a select statement, which throws the mutating error exception.

I'm not sure I perfectly understand what you're trying to do, but you should be able to build the **CLOB** yourself just by concatenating yourself with the column names. Like this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME
AFTER  UPDATE
    ON TABLE_NAME 
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    l_clob := 'Column1 ' || old.column1 || ', Column2 ' || old.column2; --For as many columns as are in the table
    --Now you have a clob with all the old values, insert it where you want it
END;
```

And then go from there. If you really want the XML format you can do that yourself as well, just concatenate the strings together.

Comment: Thanks @bobroxsox for your response. Now I use concatenating to do this but I thought it was possible to automate this process, but after what I see it's not.